# Conditional negative binomial

Tags: probability

> An urn contains white and black balls with $p_w=p$ and $p_b=1−p$. Some extractions with replacement are made. $X_a$ is the random variable representing the number of extractions made in order to get the $a$th white ball and follow a negative binomial distribution:
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(X_a=k)=\binom{k-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^{k-a}$$
>
> Is correct that if $a\lt b$ then
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(X_a=s\mid X_b=t)=0?$$

First edit:

Like Andrè says, I'm looking for the conditional distribution of $X_a$ given that $X_b=t$.

$$\mathbb{P}(X_a=s\mid X_b=t)=
\begin{cases} 0  & \text{if $a\lt b$ and $s\gt t$}\\ 0  & \text{if $a\gt b$ and $s\lt t$} \\\mathbb{P}(X_{a-b}=s-t)  & \text{if $a\gt b$ and $s\gt t$} \\ ?  & \text{if $a\lt b$ and $s\lt t$}\end{cases}$$

Edit with solution:

if $a\lt b$ and $s\lt t$ then

$$\mathbb{P}(X_a=s\mid X_b=t)=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_a=s\cap X_b=t)}{\mathbb{P}(X_b=t)}=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_a=s)\mathbb{P}(X_b=t \mid X_a=s)}{\mathbb{P}(X_b=t)}=\dfrac{\mathbb{P}(X_a=s)\mathbb{P}(X_{b-a}={t-s})}{\mathbb{P}(X_b=t)}=\dfrac{\binom{s-1}{a-1}p^a(1-p)^{s-a}\cdot\binom{t-s-1}{b-a-1}p^{b-a}(1-p)^{t-s-b+a}}{\binom{t-1}{b-1}p^b(1-p)^{t-b}}=\\ \displaystyle\dfrac{\displaystyle\binom{s-1}{a-1}\binom{t-s-1}{b-a-1}}{\displaystyle\binom{t-1}{b-1}}$$

Comment: The probability depends on $s$ and $t$. For some values, in particular $s\ge t$, it is $0$.

Comment: So if $a \lt b$ and $s \lt t$ is not zero? Is related to memorylessness?

Comment: It can be $0$. For it takes at least $b-a$ turns to get from $a$ successes to $b$ successes. You have not made it clear what you really want. The answer to your explicit question is easy, the conditional probability is not necessarily $0$. But I suspect you want the conditional distribution of $X_a$ given that $X_b=t$.  Or something like that. If you want an answer, the actual problem you want to solve should be made clear.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I've edited my question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a a fair number of cases. A useful breakdown is $a=b$, $a\gt b$, and $a\lt b$. We look only at the case $a\lt b$ and $s\lt t$, since that is the case specifically asked about in the edited question.

We might as well use the ordinary conditional probability formalism to guide the calculation. Let $B$ be the event $X_b=t$ and $A$ be the event $X_a=s$. We want $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. You know an explicit expression for $\Pr(B)$.

So now all we need is $\Pr(A\cap B)$, which is $\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)$. You know an explicit expression for $\Pr(A)$, so all we need is $\Pr(B\mid A)$. This is $\Pr(X_{b-a}=t-s)$. If $t-s\lt b-a$, we have $\Pr(X_{b-a}=t-s)=0$. For  $t-s\ge b-a$, you know an explicit expression for $\Pr(X_{b-a}=t-s)$. Now put the pieces together to calculate $\Pr(A\mid B)$. There will be significant simplification.

Comment: Hi, I did the math :-)

Comment: @Paul: Good. Sometimes, even when there might be a quicker way, it is useful to go through the conditional probability machinery. Intuition in these things can be unreliable.